# Graphviz (4net) to DOT conversion

Tags: c#, graphviz

I have the following code (converted from C# using graphviz4net):

```
digraph g {
graph [rankdir="LR" ,compound="true" ];
    subgraph cluster0 {
        graph [label="Ready" ];
        1 [  ];
    };
    subgraph cluster2 {
        graph [label="Paused" ];
        3 [  ];
    };
    1 -> 3 [ ltail="cluster0" ,lhead="cluster2" ,comment="4"  ];
    3 -> 1 [ ltail="cluster2" ,lhead="cluster0" ,comment="5"  ];
}
```

I'm checking the converted image on http://www.graphviz-dev.appspot.com/.

The image is like this:

[image: Image converted with Graphviz]

I'm programming in C#. I have 2 questions:

1 - How to fix the arrows in C#?

2 - How to make the ellipses disapear in C#?

*I know I can use node [shape = none], but I don't know how to set it in C#.

**UPDATE:**

Now I've got the following code:

```
digraph g {
graph [rankdir="LR" ,compound="true" ];
    subgraph cluster0 {
        graph [label="Ready\n\nPurchaser:\noperation1,operation2,Supplier:\noperation1,operation3," ];
        1 [ shape="none" ,fontcolor="white"  ];
    };
    subgraph cluster2 {
        graph [label="Paused\n\nPurchaser:\noperation1,operation3,Supplier:\noperation2,operation3," ];
        3 [ shape="none" ,fontcolor="white"  ];
    };
    subgraph cluster4 {
        graph [label="Completed\n\nPurchaser:\noperation4,Supplier:\noperation4," ];
        5 [ shape="none" ,fontcolor="white"  ];
    };
    1 -> 3 [ ltail="cluster0" ,lhead="cluster2" ,comment="6"  ];
    1 -> 5 [ ltail="cluster0" ,lhead="cluster4" ,comment="7"  ];
    3 -> 1 [ ltail="cluster2" ,lhead="cluster0" ,comment="8"  ];
    3 -> 5 [ ltail="cluster2" ,lhead="cluster4" ,comment="9"  ];
}
```

Which gives me:

[image: Graphviz4net]

Don't worry about the label problems, I'll fix that.

The C# code is as it follows:

```
Graph<State> Graph = new Graph<State> { Rankdir = RankDirection.LeftToRight };
```

A stringBuilder generates the subgraphs

```
// returns new SubGraph<State>{ Label = stringBuilder.ToString()};
var stringNewBlock = ConvertBlockToSubgraph(state);
```

Inside ConvertBlockToSubgraph

```
foreach (var allowedOperation in allowedOperationList)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(allowedOperation.Key +":\\n");

                foreach (var operation in allowedOperation.Value)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(!operation.Equals(lastAllowedOperation) ? operation + ",": operation);
                }
            }
```

Back to outside world:

```
var subgraphNewBlock = new SubGraph<State>{ Label = stringBuilder.ToString()};


stringNewBlock.AddVertex(state);
Graph.AddSubGraph(stringNewBlock);
```

Then I generate the Edges with:

```
public override IBlockHandling<State> GenerateLinks()
{
    foreach (var state in statesDictionary.Values)
    {
        foreach (var nextPossibleState in state.GetNextPossibleStateList())
        {
            if (statesDictionary.ContainsKey(nextPossibleState))
            {
                var sourceSubGraph = Graph.SubGraphs.Single(x => x.Label.Contains(state.GetMainHeaderName()));
                var destinationSubGraph = Graph.SubGraphs.Single(x => x.Label.Contains(nextPossibleState));
                var edge = new Edge<SubGraph<State>>(sourceSubGraph, destinationSubGraph);
                Graph.AddEdge(edge);
            }

        }
    }

    return this;
}
```

Then I convert to the DOT Format with:

```
    public override IBlockHandling<State> ConvertDtoToDot()
    {
        var writer = new StringWriter();
        new GraphToDotConverter().Convert(writer, Graph, new AttributesProvider());
        var result = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString().Trim();

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        return this;
    }
```

**The problem I still have are the arrows looking weird.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide C# code of the graph that you feed into Graphviz4Net so that it produces this output?

Comment: @Steves , I can't fix that problem. I edited the question with my current state. Please, take a look and tell me if you know how to fix it. The code I have is filled with system details

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is in the arrows shape, please see the below code:

```
var edge = new Edge<SubGraph<State>>(sourceSubGraph, destinationSubGraph , 
     new Arrow(),  new DiamondArrow());
```

For more info please check the below :

[Graphviz4Net](https://github.com/tomap/Graphviz4Net)